# Need some clarification with "High definition time-stamps" (win32, direct3d, performance counter)

Tags: c++, winapi

I just went to the documentation that explains the [QueryPerformanceCounter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644904%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method and also the documentation that explains the use of [High resolution time stamps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn553408%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). These documentations have good explanations about the use of the methods.

But I just have a few questions about the performance counter. The documentation about the counter elaborates that it uses a hardware counter to count the number of ticks at a constant rate.

My question is what do they mean by "ticks"? Are ticks just part of a timer that the system has?

Comment: http://superuser.com/q/101183/64178 (don't mind the UNIX nature of the question; this is a general computing term) (basically, _yes_)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "tick" is a time unit, the smallest increment of the counter.  As the articles you read pointed out, the exact length of a tick depends on hardware.  You need to convert the difference between two tick values to seconds by dividing by the QueryPerformanceFrequency().  Roughly:

```
LARGE_INTEGER startTick, endTick, totalTicks, frequency;
QueryPerformanceCounter(&startTick);
// Do stuff
//...
QueryPerformanceCounter(&endTick);
totalTicks.QuadPart = endTick.QuadPart - startTick.QuadPart;
QueryPerformanceFrequency(&frequency);
double seconds = static_cast<double>(totalTicks.QuadPart) / frequency.QuadPart;
```

Comment: I have one more question about "ticks". Even though I stated that the hardware counter counts ticks at a constant rate, when does the counter actually start counting ticks? does it start counting when the compiler starts to translate the code?--- if so, then does that mean a tick is counted when a line of code is read by the compiler?

Comment: Unspecified, but you can be pretty sure that it starts at 0 when the power cord has been unplugged for a while.  It just doesn't matter, you always measure an interval.  Always two calls to QPC.  It is a stopwatch, not a clock.